# Code to Sum up the first 1234 multiples of 3 and 5 does not print anything

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm trying to write some Fortran 90 code to sum up the first 1234 multiples of 3 and 5 (including multiples of both). Here is my code so far:

```
program sum
implicit none 
integer :: x
integer :: y = 5
integer :: z = 3
integer :: n
if (mod(x,y) == 0 .or. mod(x,z) ==0) then
 print *, x
 n = x
 n = x + x
end if
end program sum
```

However, this code does not print anything to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Your code tests the value of `x` in the `if` condition:

```
  if (mod(x,y) == 0 .or. mod(x,z) ==0
```

but the value of `x` is not set at all. Therefore the result of the program is completely undefined. You need to create some kind of loop. Better two loops.

The most naive approach is to loop from 1 and test all numbers with the above if condition and stop when you have found the desired number of multiples.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. What kind of loop do you suggest? I've added x = 1, and it now prints out 1 very large number, so I need to limit it to the first 1234 multiples. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: A DO WHILE or other DO loop is worth considering. If you compile with some bounds and uninitialised variable flags, then it can hop in the initial stages.